# fullscreen background image and toggle visibility of header

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I try to load a fullscreen background image in my ionic project and toggle the header (show/hide). Unfortunately it looks like the fullscreen=true won't work.

Template:

```
<ion-header (click)="toggleHeaderClass()" [ngClass]="isTransparent ? 'transparent' : ''">
  <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-back-button defaultHref="home"></ion-back-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content 
  fullscreen="true"
  class="contentContainer"
  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + background + ')'}"
  [routerLink]="['/show', id, filterId, custom"
  routerDirection="root">
...
```

[image: ion-content is still not in fullscreen]

---

Still not the perfect solution, but it works for me! (toolbar inside ion-content):

```
<ion-content 
  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + imgSrc + ')'}">

      <ion-toolbar
        [ngClass]="{ 'visable' : hovering }"
        (click)="hovering=true">
          <ion-buttons slot="start" *ngIf="hovering" (click)="doSomething()">
            <ion-icon class="homeIcon" size="large" name="home"></ion-icon>
          </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
      ...
```

Comment: is there any CSS applied in the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your content padding to zero to all sides. Read more in `[the Ionic Documentation][1]`.

Comment: There are no paddings or margins on ion-content